# Get values of multiple checkboxes on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, dynamic, android-checkbox

I have one of these for each day of the week:

```
mondayRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mondayRadioButton.isChecked()){
            deleteAppointmentsLayout.removeAllViews();
            daySelected = 1;
            for(Iterator<Appointment> i = appointments.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
                 Appointment item = i.next();
                     if(item.getDay() == 1){
                         checkBox = new CheckBox(DeleteAppointmentActivity.this);
                         System.out.println("fucken did work");
                         id = item.getId();
                         time = item.getTime();
                         duration = item.getDuration();
                         description = item.getDescription();
                         boxText = time + ", " + duration + ", " + description;
                         checkBox.setText(boxText);
                         checkBox.setTextSize(12);
                         checkBox.setId((int) id);
                         deleteAppointmentsLayout.addView(checkBox);
                     }
                     else {
                         System.out.println("fucken didnt work");
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

When an onclick for a button is activated I want to retrieve the information for each of the selected checkboxes for the currently selected day (checkboxes are generated programmatically). How can I check which ones are selected when the onclick for the Delete button is activated?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create a member variable `Array` like

```
public class MyClass extends Activity
{
     ArrayList<CheckBox> cbArray = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

then when you create a checkbox add it to the `ArrayList`. Now when you click the delete `Button` use a `for loop` to iterate over the `ArrayList` and call `isChecked()` on each one.
Then delete or add that to a checked `Array` to do whatever you need with it

```
for (int i=0; i<cbArray.size(); i++)
{
   if (cbArray.get(i).isChecked())
  {
      // do whatever here
```